# How can I find info about the train or bus from Murfatlar (Basarabi) to Bucharest?

Tags: trains, buses, romania, bucharest

I woke up at Murfatlar station (formerly Basarabi station) in the Constanța state/province/department/etc of Romania after failing miserably to hitchhike to Bucharest from the coast.

Only the waiting room at the station is open and the few signs and notices are in Romanian. There is a timetable on the wall which suggests the next train to Bucharest is about 1pm but I don't trust it since Constanța-Bucharest should be a major route and I've had experiences with dodgy train timetables in other countries on other trips.

I do have great internet access but despite my Google expertise I can't seem to find information on this route and the paid links that come up don't include my station.

I also know there are buses (coaches) and perhaps minibuses but if the train is cheaper and slower I'd prefer to take it.

Where can I find the times and prices of trains and buses on this route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an official site for the [Romanian railways](http://www.cfr.ro/), and according to it, there is really a [train from Constanta to the Bucharest](http://www.mersultrenurilorcfr.ro/trs.asp?idtrv=30057420&cbodata=8/22/2011&lng=2), which will be at your station at 13:06 local time.

There is no other trains to the Bucharest, [according to the same site](http://www.mersultrenurilorcfr.ro/PlSo.asp?vbSta=1&idSta=72339&cboData=8/22/2011&tip=0&SubmitStatii=Search&lng=2) (and [here](http://www.mersultrenurilorcfr.ro/R3.asp?cboDeLa=72339&cboPinaLa=80074&cboVia=0&cboData=8/22/2011%208:33:56%20AM&PleStart=00:00&PleEnd=23:59&SosStart=00:00&SosEnd=23:59&cboSort=2&txtTrnImpSos=&txtTrnImpPle=&cboNrMaxConex=0&cboAbatere=150&txtNrInreg=10&Submit=Search&lng=2)), so I think this train will be :)
According this site, the price will be [`23.8 RON`](http://www.mersultrenurilorcfr.ro/trf3.asp?cboRezervare=N&txtTipBilet=bilet_intreg&txtCls=B&txtIdTrv=30057420&txtDst=200&txtRng=P&txtDeLa=Murfatlar%20hc&txtPinaLa=Bucuresti%20Obor&txtTrn=8014&txtToti=0&cboData=8/22/2011%208:33:56%20AM&lng=2).

All I can find about the romanian buses is [this site](http://www.busstation.net/main/busrom.htm) with the list of sites.

Most informative was [this one](http://www.autogari.ro/bileteAutocar.php), but I can't find any bus from Murfatlar there, only from Constanța station (near `55 RON`), so I think the train will be cheaper.

Comment: Wow how did you find that. I did find the Romanian rail site after I asked here but all I could find was [a train at 6:44pm via Ciulnița](http://infofer.ro/R3.asp?cboDeLa=72339&cboPinaLa=80036&cboVia=0&cboData=8%2F22%2F2011&PleStart=04%3A00&PleEnd=19%3A30&SosStart=00%3A00&SosEnd=23%3A59&cboSort=2&txtTrnImpSos=&txtTrnImpPle=&cboNrMaxConex=0&cboAbatere=150&txtNrInreg=10&Submit=Search&lng=2). I found another bus site but it insisted I had to go all the way back to Constanța too. Thanks!

Comment: @hippietrail Hehehe, russian tourists are best advisers - there are a lot of tips in Russian internet. Also I want to note that your variant is [`48.5 RON`](http://infofer.ro/trf3.asp?cboRezervare=N&txtTipBilet=bilet_intreg&txtCls=B&txtIdTrv=30057860&txtDst=101%2C102&txtRng=P%2CR&txtDeLa=Murfatlar+hc&txtPinaLa=Bucuresti+Baneasa&txtTrn=8344%2C991&txtToti=1&cboData=8%2F22%2F2011&lng=2)

Comment: Simple search: [Мурфатлар автобус до бухареста](http://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0&hl=en), [first result](http://www.easyvisa.com.ua/article/a-166.html), [site for the train timetables and prices](http://www.cfr.ro/).

Comment: At the petrol station where I am now in Poarta Alba they insisted the train doesn't stop here but I showed them the page you link to and they changed their mind. If the train comes then I'll accept your answer (-:

Comment: @hippietrail Good luck :)